How.can I variably adjust the rpm of one of three rotating shaft to make it .ove faster or slower, but the other two shafts move at same rpm?
I'm making a machine with two feed rollers that are linked together and chain driven and a third shaft with a cutter on it. There will be two sets of these three one on top of the other to make both rollers. So all the shafts will be placed like the Pips on the six side of a dice. I want to be able to change the speed that the last pair rotates that in relation to the first two to lengthen or shorten the cut. So is there a way that I can isolate that pair of shafts and introduce some sort of mechanism that can adjust the input speed? Or would it be simpler and easier to just add a second motor and just adjust the speed that that pair turns by adjusting the RPMs of the motor?

have you read what you wrote?

if they are chain driven, as you state, then selecting between two sets of gear ratios would work, if not consider changing the drive to a variable pulley system as used in the variomatic gearbox.
